# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given names

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My module level `build.gradle` file looks like this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appsfreelocker.puppy.pattern.lockscreen"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.1.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.kila.apprater_dialog.lars:apprater-dialog:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
}
```

And the project level `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And `gradle-wrapper.properties` like this:

```
#Mon Apr 09 17:06:49 IST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

---

When I try to make a build, the build fails and gives this error:

```
C:/Users/abc/Desktop/PuppyLockscreen    
app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v23/values-v23.xml  
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.    
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.   
app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml  
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'. 
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
```

Gradle Verison is `2.10` and Android Plugin Version is `2.0.0`

I have used [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#200_april_2016) reference to make sure that I am using the correct combination of Gradle versions, Android Plugin Version, compileSdkVersion, and buildToolsVersion.

Can anyone please point out whats causing the error and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library

```
compile 'com.kila.apprater_dialog.lars:apprater-dialog:1.0.5'
```

has a [dependency](https://github.com/Lars3n95/AppRater-Dialog/blob/master/build.gradle#L63) with

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'.
```

Then you have to use:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
```

Comment: thanks, can u answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237916/why-some-apps-dont-need-auto-run-permission-to-run-services-in-background-in-xi